# Problems Running Monodroid application with Db4o

Tags: xamarin.android

My monodroid application builds fine and deploys to the device; however the application dies on start up and the DDMS shows the following error:

*01-07 17:04:57.607: E/mono(875): Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Db4objects.Db4o, Version=8.0.224.15975, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6199cd4f203aa8eb' or one of its dependencies.*

I have confirmed I am referencing DB4O and it shows up in the bin/debug directory.

Given this error I would think that db4o does not work with Monodroid but I have another Monodroid project which uses db4o and it works.

I have a feeling something is broken with the project file but not sure what to do.  I have tried removing and adding the db4o reference a couple of times.

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and the latest version of Mondodroid as of 1/7/2012.  I am deploying to a an Android 3.2 emulator.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're running into a bug in the current version of Mono for Android that has to do with Fast Deployment. In the project's properties, under the Mono Android Options section, uncheck the box for Use Fast Deployment. You'll probably need to do a clean build as well to make sure it takes effect.

Comment: Thanks Greg, that did the trick.  BTW, thanks for the effort you put into your blog posts and for the source code up on GitHub, you have been a great resource in my efforts to learn Monodroid.  Thanks again.